# How do I create and initialize an immutable array?

Tags: arrays, immutability, rust

I want to create an array. I don't need the array to be mutable, and at the time of creation, I have all the information I need to calculate the i-th member of the array. However, can't figure out how to create an immutable array in Rust.

Here's what I have now:

```
let mut my_array: [f32; 4] = [0.0; 4];
for i in 0..4 {
    // some calculation, doesn't matter what exactly
    my_array[i] = some_function(i);
}
```

And here's what I want:

```
let my_array: [f32; 4] = array_factory!(4, some_function);
```

How can I achieve that in Rust?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the macro definition with sample usage:

```
macro_rules! array_factory(
    ($size: expr, $factory: expr) => ({
        unsafe fn get_item_ptr<T>(slice: *mut [T], index: usize) -> *mut T {
            (slice as *mut T).offset(index as isize)
        }

        let mut arr = ::std::mem::MaybeUninit::<[_; $size]>::uninit();
        unsafe {
            for i in 0..$size {
                ::std::ptr::write(get_item_ptr(arr.as_mut_ptr(), i), $factory(i));
            }
            arr.assume_init()
        }
    });
);

fn some_function(i: usize) -> f32 {
    i as f32 * 3.125
}

fn main() {
    let my_array: [f32; 4] = array_factory!(4, some_function);
    println!("{} {} {} {}", my_array[0], my_array[1], my_array[2], my_array[3]);
}
```

The macro's body is essentially your first version, but with a few changes:

- The type annotation on the array variable is omitted, because it can be inferred.
- The array is created uninitialized, because we're going to overwrite all values immediately anyway. Messing with uninitialized memory is unsafe, so we must operate on it from within an `unsafe` block. Here, we're using [`MaybeUninit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html), which was introduced in Rust 1.36 to replace [`mem::uninitialized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.uninitialized.html)<sup>1</sup>.
- Items are assigned using [`std::ptr::write()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ptr/fn.write.html) due to the fact that the array is uninitialized. Assignment would try to drop an uninitialized value in the array; the effects depend on the array item type (for types that implement `Copy`, like `f32`, it has no effect; for other types, it could crash).
- The macro body is a block expression (i.e. it's wrapped in braces), and that block ends with an expression that is not followed by a semicolon, `arr.assume_init()`. The result of that block expression is therefore `arr.assume_init()`.

Instead of using unsafe features, we can make a safe version of this macro; however, it requires that the array item type implements the [`Default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/default/trait.Default.html) trait. Note that we must use normal assignment here, to ensure that the default values in the array are properly dropped.

```
macro_rules! array_factory(
    ($size: expr, $factory: expr) => ({
        let mut arr = [::std::default::Default::default(), ..$size];
        for i in 0..$size {
            arr[i] = $factory(i);
        }
        arr
    });
)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> And for a good reason. The previous version of this answer, which used `mem::uninitialized`, was not memory-safe: if a panic occurred while initializing the array (because the factory function panicked), and the array's item type had a destructor, the compiler would insert code to call the destructor on every item in the array; even the items that were not initialized yet! `MaybeUninit` avoids this problem because it wraps the value being initialized in [`ManuallyDrop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/struct.ManuallyDrop.html), which is a magic type in Rust that prevents the destructor from running automatically.

Comment: +1 Nice! But I'm almost sure your assignment is wrong. You need to use `::std::ptr::write` instead. Otherwise `drop` is called on uninitialized values.

Comment: I wonder whether `[std::uninitialized(),..N]` is a no-op or involves N function calls. I think a single `std::uninitialized()` for the whole array is a better approach.

Comment: Look at the generated asm [on the playpen](http://is.gd/tc9lnB) with -O2. It seems to be initializing the whole array with 2 moves in this example. With -O0, it is calling `uninitialized()`, but not in a loop.

Comment: Thanks! But coming from C#, I have a habit of avoiding `unsafe` blocks as much as possible. (BTW, is it still a good habit in Rust or should I drop it?) Do I understand correctly that the only reason you used unsafe blocks is not to rely on `Default::default()` being implemented?

Comment: @golergka: Avoiding `unsafe` is still a good habit. In this case it's used to avoid the issue of having to initialize the array with some dummy element.

Comment: @golergka: I used unsafe blocks for 2 reasons: not requiring the array item type to implement `Default`, and not writing default values to an array that we're going to immediately replace anyway. BTW, I edited my answer to include the safe version too, for completeness.

Comment: Creating an array from a function should be a rust feature: you can be sure that everything will be initialized, it does not need to be unsafe !

Answer (score 3):

Now, there is a (pretty popular) crate to do that exact thing: [array_init](https://crates.io/crates/array-init)

```
use array_init::array_init;
let my_array: [f32; 4] = array_init(some_function);
```

##### PS:

There is a lot of discussion and evolution around creating abstractions around arrays inside the rust team.

For example, the [map](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html#impl) function for arrays is already available, and it will become stable in rust 1.55.

If you wanted to, you could implement your function with map:

```rust
#![feature(array_map)]
let mut i = 0usize;
result = [(); 4].map(|_| {v = some_function(i);i = i+1; v})
```

And there are even discussions around your particular problem, you can look [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/2092)

Comment: It's a mistake, I will edit my answer. Thanks !

Comment: I updated my answer. Do you think my PS is more fair ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to make your macro expand to this:

```
let my_array = {
    let mut tmp: [f32, ..4u] = [0.0, ..4u];
    for i in range(0u, 4u) {
        tmp[i] = somefunction(i);
    }
    tmp
};
```

What I don't know is whether this is properly optimized to avoid moving `tmp` to `my_array`. But for 4 f32 values (128 bits) it probably does not make a significant difference.