# How to populate an array without using mut?

Tags: arrays, rust

If I wanted to populate a list of numbers, I can use a vector, and hence the heap, by doing this:

```
let w = (0..1024).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

But, if I wanted to avoid the heap I have to use an array. To use an array, I have to use a loop which means I must have a mutable variable:

```
let mut w = [0u32; 1024];
for i in 0..1024 {
    w[i] = i as u32;
}
```

Is it possible to populate an array without using mutable variables?

---

This question has been flagged as a dup. I'm not sure how this can possibly be confused.

"How to populate an array without using mut?" means how do I populate an array without using a mutable variable to do so. Any `mut`, not just the array variable itself.

"How do I create and initialize an immutable array?" means how do I create an immutable array.

Comment: Is _"without using mutable variables"_ an artificial constraint? Creating the array and then doing `for v in &mut w {` or `for v in w.iter_mut()` would appear to be the usual way of doing this. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26185618/1233251

Comment: Of course you can limit the mutability to a nested scope: `let w = { let mut array = ...; ...; array };`.

Comment: @E_net4 does `for v in &mut w {` work if `w` is not declated as mutable to begin with?

Comment: it does not without declaring `w` as mutable, thus why I'm asking.

Comment: @E_net4 Yes. I am avoiding using mutable variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create and initialize an immutable array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26435046/how-do-i-create-and-initialize-an-immutable-array)

Comment: @E_net4 Not a duplicate. The questions are distinctly different.

Comment: What about this one? https://stackoverflow.com/q/26757355/1233251

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

`Iterator` can't guarantee any specific length at compile time, so `.collect()` can't produce fixed-size arrays.

You can do:

```rust
let w = w;
```

to recreate the binding as immutable afterwards, or move the initialization to a helper function.

Answer (score 0):

You can [create an immutable variable whose value is a `&mut [T; N]`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fefc9fa3c8c75d267fe6cbcc996046e9):

```
pub fn main() {
    let a = &mut [1, 2, 3];
    a[0] = 42;
    println!("{:?}", a);
    // a = &mut [1; 3]; // error[E0384]: cannot assign twice to immutable variable `a`
    print_type_of(&a); // &mut [i32; 3]
}

fn print_type_of<T>(_: &T) {
    println!("{}", std::any::type_name::<T>())
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer is **NO**.                                  ⠀